# Rails polymorphic association that multiple models access the same thing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations, polymorphism

How do you set up a polymorphic association where two different models have access to the same item

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images, :as => :imageable
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images, :as => :imageable
end
```

I would like ModelA and ModelB to access the same Image. So if ModelA updates an image ModelB image will be updated also.

**UPDATE**

I am attempting to create something like the following

[image]

```
Event has many images
Person has many images
Person and Event reference the same image
When a image is added to a person from an Event the record has extra attributes.
```

Can this be done though a polymorphic association?

Thank you

Comment: is all fields in modelA and modelB are same?? and is this is one sided or both side..?

Comment: I added an update, hopefully that will give you more info on what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the relation between ModelA and ModelB to do this. Because images are not shared within ModelA. eg:

```
ModelA.find(1).images
```

is different from

```
ModelA.find(2).images
```

**EDIT**
If i understand correctly, you dont need a polymorphic relation here.

You can just create this relation

In Person Model

```
has_many :event_images, :through => :person_event_images
```

Comment: I added an update. Its should make more sense on what i am trying to do.